# Materialized view

Tags: postgresql, view

Estou com um problema para criar uma view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW table_name
```

Está dando este erro:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "MATERIALIZED" LINE 1: CREATE
>   MATERIALIZED VIEW sige.view_geral_lote AS ^ ********** Error
>
> ---
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "MATERIALIZED" SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 8

quando tento criar esta view mas não sei o motivo do erro, poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Olá Gabriel, *"mas não sei o motivo do erro"* nós também não, qual a mensagem de erro? pode colocar o código sql completo que está executando para ajudar a entender o erro?

Comment: Desculpe pela falta de informação

segue abaixo o erro que está dando 

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MATERIALIZED"
LINE 1: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sige.view_geral_lote AS 
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "MATERIALIZED"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 8

Comment: Gabriel, você pode adicionar a mensagem na pergunta, fica melhor pra analisar. Clica no link "editar" [ou aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/315543/edit) e adiciona a mensagem lá

Comment: ah, coloque o comando completo também, está dando erro no corpo da view, na parte de select provavelmente

Comment: Qual é a versão do PostgreSQL? Lembrando que o `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` está disponivel somente após à 9.3 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html